# Why does this while loop loop forever?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have tried looking at documentation and could not figure it out. My while loop does not stop and prints "ya" forever. What am I doing wrong?

```
var ya = 1;
Formitivegrades = [100, 95, 100, 85, 100]
Formitiaveav1 = Formitivegrades[0] + Formitivegrades[1] + Formitivegrades[3] + Formitivegrades[4] + Formitivegrades[2]
Formitiaveav2 = Formitiaveav1 / 5

sumgrades = [100]
sumav1 = ya + sumgrades[0]
sumav2 = sumav1 / 2

averge = .4 * Formitiaveav2 + .6 * sumav2

while(averge < 95){
    console.log(ya)
    ya++;
}

console.log(averge)
```

Comment: you need to recalculate the average in the while loop

Comment: `averge` never changes. So the loop will always be true

Comment: `averge` will always be `68.7` and It is not changing, so the loop runs forever.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of the equal sign `=` as an equality that is guaranteed forever, the way it is in mathematics. In programming it is a one-time assignment. An assignment statement gives a variable a new value at that moment in time only. If they change values afterwards the equality can be broken.

If `ya` is updated that does not cause `sumav1` to be recalculated. Nor does `sumav2` change whenever `sumav1` changes, nor `avrge` when `sumav2` changes. `averge` keeps the same value forever unless you explicitly update it.

To that end, you need to recompute all of the variables each time you change `ya`. That way `averge` can eventually reach `95` and cause the loop to end.

```
while(averge < 95){
    console.log(ya)
    ya++;

    sumav1 = ya + sumgrades[0]
    sumav2 = sumav1 / 2
    averge = .4 * Formitiaveav2 + .6 * sumav2
}
```